# How to prevent closing of parent window before child window is closed

Tags: python, tkinter, ubuntu-16.04

I know that, from [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.grab_set-method),

> grab_set() [#]:
>   Routes all events for this application to this widget.

OK but it doesn't prevent the user to close the parent window with X button. In addition to other events, how can I route "X button close" event as well?

**MWE:**

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)


class MainWindow(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        Button(self, command=self.open_window).grid(row=0, column=0)

    def open_window(self):
        win = Window(self)
        win.grab_set()


app = MainWindow()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have updated my answer let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: what is your actual question? What do you wish to change/ accomplish?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I want to prevent the user closing the parent window before closing child window.

Comment: Ok I get that but why is that the desired behaviour? do you mean to be able to open any number of child windows or just one? Should the program give you any indication that the child window needs to be closed before the parent can? should the two windows be allowed to close independently of each other?  I don't understand what the end goal is here.

Answer (score 1):

For windows you can use:

`root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", your_function_here)`

I don't know about other operating systems as I have not tested it on anything other than windows.

Works fine in a class as well.

`self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.your_method_here)`

I have added some code to your post to illustrate its use. Note when you press the X button the program will rune the close_program method.

Edit: Without being able to test on Mac I have added what I think will fix your problem. I have added an if statement in the close_program method to check if the top level exist before attempting to close.

Update: I added a check for the variable `win` to deal with possible errors if toplevel was never opened but still trying to close root window.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_program)

    def close_program(self):
        print ("destroying Window")
        self.destroy()


class MainWindow(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        Button(self, command=self.open_window).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_program)

    def open_window(self):
        global win
        win = Window(self)
        win.grab_set()

    def close_program(self):
        if 'win' in globals():
            if win.winfo_exists() == 1:
                print("top level still active")
            else:
                print("destroying MainWindow")
                self.destroy()
        else:
            print("destroying MainWindow")
            self.destroy()


app = MainWindow()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can still close the parent window before the child with your code. So no change.

Comment: Hum. I was not able to. I will work on it when my lunch is over. I suspect it should be easy to create an if statements to check if child window is open before attempting to close.

Comment: BTW, I can say on mac doing File->Close or cmd-W also triggers that protocol.  And I believe linux does as well.

Comment: @Shibli: I have updated my answer with an if statement that should prevent the root window from closing if top level exist. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that if the child window exists, trying to close the parent window will put it into focus, this would require a few changes:

1. override the close protocol with `.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")` so it checks for a child window.
2. Keep a reference to a child window

```
class MainWindow(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        Button(self, text="hello there", command=self.open_window).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.try_to_close)
        self.win = None

    def open_window(self):
        if self.win is None or not self.win.winfo_exists():
            self.win = Window(self)
        self.win.lift(self)
        self.win.focus_set()

    def try_to_close(self):
        if self.win is not None and self.win.winfo_exists():
            self.win.lift()
        else:
            self.destroy()
```

Comment: Yeah it does what I want. Also, adding `self.win.grab_set()` after `self.win.focus_set()` also prevents clicking the button in parent. Nice.